# how to use distinct in join when i have null value

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have this Table with this content:

[image: enter link description here]

And I have this Query :

```
select sc.*,df.Name,foods.FoodName
from R_Schedule as sc
  left join R_DaysOfWeek as df on sc.DayId=df.DayId
  join R_Foods as foods on sc.FoodId=foods.FoodId
where  sc.dayId=6 or sc.dayId is null
```

I getting this result :

[image: enter link description here]

Instead of :

[image: enter link description here]

I want get all record but not repeat by food id .  my query return two rows with same food id .
I tring use Distinct but i dont can get any answer .

how can I do this ?

[3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jYy1X.png):

[image: Updated content of data :see]

Comment: sc.dayId is not null

Comment: some times i need get some rows when dayid is null .

Comment: You can use http://sqlfiddle.com/ to test your data

Comment: So how do you decide which of the two rows to keep. The one that's doesn't have a null?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `Row_Number()` to get what you want.

```
SELECT data.*
FROM
    (
      SELECT 
           sc.*,df.Name,foods.FoodName ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY foods.foodID ORDER BY sc.ScheduleID) as rn
      FROM R_Schedule as sc
       left join R_DaysOfWeek as df on sc.DayId=df.DayId
       join R_Foods as foods on sc.FoodId=foods.FoodId 
      where  sc.dayId=6  
    ) AS data
WHERE
  data.rn = 1
```

Comment: I run your code but I getting this ERROR : `The column 'DayId' was specified multiple times for 'data'.`

Comment: Why you don't care about sc.DayId =null?

Comment: Because that condition OP was trying to filter out the rows that possible could have given him the result. But that is not the problem with OP's query. If you read query and compare with the data he as given you can understand it.

Comment: This answer will only work as long as the row you want to keep have the lower number foodID. Is that really going to work in every case?